Why do different computers return the same MAC address?
I have access to different machines running my Python code. I would like to get the MAC address of a network card of each of these machines. Following this thread, I use:
import uuid
uuid.getnode()

and I get the same number on different machines: 190070690681122, which I convert to the usual format with:
":".join(f"{b:02x}" for b in uuid.getnode().to_bytes(6, "big"))

and I get ac:de:48:00:11:22, which is different from the MAC address I see on Network Preferences. I am curious why several machines return the same number, so I searched for it and found another thread that also finds this number:
en9: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 

So I believe this is specific to Apple computers.
On another Mac, I ran this code and got this same number, but running it four days later it found another MAC address: 3e:22:fb:..., when the actual MAC address is different by one letter: 3c:22:fb....
What is the source of the problem, and how can I reliably get the actual MAC address of a Mac computer (no pun intended)?

Not a Python programmer myself, but do any of these solutions work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address

I don't know anything about your Python command, but I'm pretty sure that it's not reporting multiple hosts with the same MAC address!  I don't know what the correct Python command is, but if you'll open your Terminal.app, and enter arp -an you may find something useful. Entering this command from a host (say host A) will tell you the MAC address of all machines in 'host A's' ARP cache. If you want to see all the options for arp, enter man arp at the Terminal command line.

I looked at what uuid.getnode() does and and... yikes. It basically runs ifconfig and picks the first thing it finds that looks like a MAC address. This seems very brittle. I actually get the same address as you, because it picks up the en3 interface, which seems to be some sort of magic used for Parallells.
Of course, any code that purports to find the MAC address of a computer is going to be brittle, because any computer can have multiple interfaces and, in today’s world where everything is virtualized, they usually have.
EDIT I wasn’t quite fair to uuid.getnode(). I doesn’t just grab the first MAC address it sees, but does some filtering to find a good candidate. However, the fact that it does this and still comes up with a useless result indicates how brittle the approach is.

Yea, computers don't have MAC addresses, network interfaces (which may be part of computers) have MAC addresses.

Thanks! Could you please add how you'd find the MAC address of a fixed network card, such as en0 on macOS, or of the card currently used to connect to the internet?

I’m sorry; I’ve never (thank goodness!) had to do this, so I don’t know any good methods, off the top of my head, I can only think of bad ones, like parsing the output of ifconfig in a more conservative way. It’s worth noticing that “the interface used to connect to the Internet” is also quite a tricky concept to pin down. You could do something like connecting to www.google.com and seeing what interface that used, but... yuck.
